# magento 2 Default image file types not acceptable

Tags: magento2, image, product-images, image-upload

I have an issue where I cannot add images to products on Magento 2.0.7.  Attempts to do so with jpg, png, jpeg, and/or gif yield the following error:

> Attention
>
> We don't recognize or support this file extension type.

I have tried every file type known to man or woman.  . Can anyone advise as to where this info is stored?  The console in Chrome says nothing at all.  The admin lists nothing.

Thanks to @krishna ijjada we can find this Javascript validation code at

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/web/catalog/base-image-uploader.js

`acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i`

My code matches this.  I can find no other instance in any forum of this happening.  Anyone else?

Answer (score 3):

Magento 2 product image validates/accepts `jpeg,.jpg,.png and gif` image/file formats.

We can find this Javascript validation code at `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/web/catalog/base-image-uploader.js`

```
acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
```

Unfortunately information (accepted types)is not provided.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please check the modified answer.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what it should say?

Comment: Is anything in my code blocking this?  `acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,`  Seems correct.

Comment: Yes , it will accepts  jpeg,.jpg,.png and gif only.

Comment: Yes I understand what its asking for, its just when I provide a jpeg, jpg, png, and/or gif, it still tells me that its not an acceptable file type.  That was the original post here.  I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: I have the same issue. No matter what type of already allowed image type I try to upload Magento will not let me add an product images.

Answer (score 0):

The host accepted blame due to an PHP config issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check phpinfo() page, if file_uploads is off, set file_uploads on

[image]