# Product Gallery Image Upload Issue in Magento 2.1.4

Tags: product-images, image-upload, magento-2.1.4, gallery-image

While uploading an image to the product gallery in magento backend product edit, I am getting the below error.

> "We Dont Recognize or Support this File Extension type"

For all extension types i am getting the same error and I am getting product Upload call response as

> "File was not uploaded" error code: 666

I have checked the pub/media folder permission and also ensured the allowed file extensions.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you:

> - Check your /tmp dir space
> - Check it's permission

Comment: What permission needs to be given for /tmp dir?

Comment: For /tmp  1777, which ls shows as drwxrwxrwt, for more, please visit: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71622/what-are-correct-permissions-for-tmp-i-unintentionally-set-it-all-public-recu#answer-71625

Answer (score 1):

In following thread, you can find other possible reasons and its solution.

[Magento 2 can not upload product images](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127586/magento-2-can-not-upload-product-images)

Hope it helps.