# Magento2, problem with uploading favicon.ico

Tags: magento-2.1.2, favicons

Going to `Admin sidebar -> Stores-> Settings ->Configuration -> General-> Design`, there is no **HTML Head** section to expand and upload the new favicon.ico! I tried to copy the favico.ico to `Magento_Theme -> web` but did not help(cache was cleaned)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload by following admin configuration path.

> Go to Admin -> Content / Configuration -> Edit Default theme -> Go to Other
>   Settings / HTML Head Click on 'Upload' button for Favicon Select .ico
>   file

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I try to upload .ico file, but it says "We don't recognize or support this file extension type."!

Comment: Please check the internal issue  link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5478

Comment: Is there alternate way to have the new favicon as uploading still is the issue.  Do you know the correct path?

Comment: Please Covert the images and upload as supportrd formats http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126427/magento-2-default-image-file-types-not-acceptable

Comment: acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe|ico?g|png)$/i, would it be correct?

Comment: Yes, I found the from core files. you can try.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload it from admin.

```
Admin >> Content >> Design >> Configuration >> Select your current theme from list >> HTML Head.
```

You can see here Fevicon Icon field, Upload you fevicon icon here.

Run command for clean cache : `php bin/magento cache:clean`